# A better word for 'Teachings'

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I'm looking for a spanish word for the english word 'teachings' (as an example: Catholic Teachings, etc). The dictionary I usually consult suggests the word 'enseñanzas', but somehow the word doesn't sound well, for me at least. Is there a better word? Instinctively, I was looking for 'ensinamientos' but this word doesn't seem to exist in the dictionary...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Enseñanzas" could work.
"ensinamientos" doesn't exist.
You must be meaning "enseñamientos".
Both could work, but I'd prefer the first one.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

In **Chile** "enseñamiento" is a word completely unknown.

We would say something like this:

> Educación católica
>
> Instrucción católica

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Incluso si "enseñamiento" está aceptada por la RAE suena mal al oído. Yo habría ido por "enseñanza" para traducir "teachings", sin embargo el usuario deja claro en la pregunta que está buscando una palabra distinta a esta.

Comment: @Diego I didn't know the word would feel incorrect to a native speaker. Is that only for South America, or for Spain also?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I'm form Spain. I can't talk for all Latin America, but based on Rodrigo's answer it seems to be really uncommon in Chile as well. BTW, I googled "Catholic Teachings", among the results I picked one website about Opus Dei which allowed to choose between different language settings, and "teachings" was translated as "enseñanzas". I didn't test all the Spanish dialects, but maybe there's one that favors "enseñamientos" over "enseñanzas".

Comment: @Diego, your ingenuity always surprises me. I learn much with you. +1. Thanks ;)